# How to test suspected hardware on Android

Tags: hardware, htc-sensation

I have a problem with my HTC Sensation that I think is either due to problems with the electronics that interfaces to the battery or a memory problem. Basically the phone turns off spontaneously by itself every now and then. Very often - as far as I can see - when the CPU is running 100% (and hence there are a big battery drain)... Turning on the phone again can easily take 2-3 turns before it is running stable (until next time). It seems to be starting first time though if connected to power...

If this occurred on a Windows PC, I would first download a hardware test/diagnostics application and see whether this could find anything...

...but for all the usual security reasons, the Android platform is way more closed than the PC/Windows platform and I suspect that it is not so easy to install a diagnostics app to test the hardware.

So... how do you go about this then? Short of using a full-blown hardware analyser, which I don't have access to :-)

[Note that I have rooted my device and don't mind flashing a new ROM if needed...]

Comment: I have edited the question to address your objection... Hope it helps

Comment: Are you running some app/widget that you recently installed (cpu 100%) is a dead give-away  to some process that is hogging it up? Try uninstalling that recently installed app and see how it fares. Another question, are you using stock ROM?

Comment: There's something else that's is hinting at me... you say "*Turning on the phone again can easily take 2-3 turns before it is running stable (until next time). It seems to be starting first time though if connected to power...*" That looks suspiciously like either an over-clocked kernel that is running a bit too high or there is a bug in the kernel.. just saying :)

Comment: @t0mm13b I'm using http://www.virtuousrom.com/p/inquisition.html - and they state "_Stock kernel, not overclocked_". So my guess still is a hardware problem in the battery interface. Though, I would love to be proved wrong!

Comment: Best to take it back to the carrier's shop to get it checked out or get someone who's an electronic whiz to open it up and check it out for you... If it comes down to that diagnosis and having to return to the carrier's shop, you may have to revert to Stock ROM so not to raise their suspicion and their refusal to test it because it has a rom other than stock on it :) More than likely you suspect right about the battery interface somewhere... :)

Comment: Just something caught my eye on the linky to virtuousrom's inquisition site.. the picture of the handset with the logo, states '*OC up to 1.5Ghz*' which implies either the description is wrong or there is indeed overclocking in there somewhere?! Unable to confirm :)

Answer (score 5):

> [StabilityTest](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.into.stability&hl=sv) is a stress-testing tool for android devices with error
>   reporting.

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments here just to keep things on-topic.

Comment: Tried StabilityTest today for 30 minutes... No problems...