# How can I test if my GPS has a hardware problem?

Tags: gps, hardware

Some days ago, my GPS stopped working. It doesn't lock, no matter how long I leave it on.

I've read [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50533/fixing-gps-lock-that-takes-too-long-without-installing-a-custom-rom) but had no luck.

Sometimes it reports that it found one GPS satellite available, but most of the time it gets none.

I also read about [stability test](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24774/how-to-test-suspected-hardware-on-android), but is doesn't seem to report GPS problems.

So, is there any test I can perform to detect if I really have a hardware GPS problem?

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S2, with android 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing and messing with: [GPS info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whiztools.gpsinfo&hl=en) and [GPS test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest)

Comment: Using GPS info gave me same results I had with GPS status: sometimes one sat becomes visible, then disappears, and nothing more than that...